# iPhone Core Data-driven Search: How To, Resources?

Tags: iphone, search, core-data

I have a very simple Core Data app which pretty much contains strings of text. I would like to make this text searchable, and can see a "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" object in Interface Builder.

Firstly, would using this Search Bar and Search Display Controller be the best approach for a simple Core Data-driven text search? Secondly, could you point me to some resources which would get me started? Possibly a nice step by step guide or a sample project – the simpler the better.

I have looked both on SO and the Apple iPhone Dev Center but I can't seem to find anything. Thanks again!

Comment: hey david, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it.
When the delegate

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

tells me the user typed something in the search bar, I create a predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"string CONTAINS[c] %@",searchText];
```

fetch the results from the MOC with this predicate, update my results array and tell the results table view to reload

```
[[self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView] reloadData];
```

If you have a lot a results you can try setting a fetch limit, and load all the results if the user presses the search button.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

Hope this helps.